# Creating html elements in zend forms

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I will like to translate this full code into a zend form with all the ids, html image elements, the classes, the spans. Everything. Am finding it difficult to add the image and to group the elements accordint to the divs and spans.
I will be grateful if anyone could help me. Thank you.

```
<form method="get" action="/search" name="searchForm" id="searchForm">
<div class="logo">
    <a href="http://trial.com" title="Trial" name="trialLogo">
    <img width="205" height="40" alt="Trial Search" src="..image/logo.png">
    </a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="/Listing" name="ref_uri">
<div class="inputBlock">
    <span class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" class="labelMagic fieldHelpText" tabindex="3" id="what" name="what" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="listingId"></span>
</div>
<div class="inputBlock">
    <span class="inputWrapper"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="Location" class="labelMagic" tabindex="4" id="where" name="where"><input type="hidden" name="geoId"></span>
</div>
<div class="submitWrapper"><button class="goButton" tabindex="5" name="go" type="submit">Go!</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly employ a collection of configured [HtmlTag decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.htmlTag) to perform all this wrapping, including setting the attributes on all these divs and spans.

But perhaps easier would be to simply employ a [ViewScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript) decorator for the form. A good example appears on this [MWOP Dev Zone article](https://web.archive.org/web/20110826042248/http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450).